# Angular Material mat-datepicker validacion formato (DD/MM/YYYY)

Tags: angular

Estoy trabajando con el mat-datepicker de Material y no consigo que al introducir una fecha manualmente en el input tenga el formato DD/MM/YYYY para que salte la validacion de que solo se acepta ese formato. He creado esta validacion personalizada pero cuando introduzco 06/02/ ya me lo da como valido y no es asi. Adjunto codigo de mi validacion personalizada:

```
export const validarFecha = (ctrl: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const myDate = new Date(ctrl.value);

  return !ctrl.value || isNaN(myDate.getTime()) || myDate.getFullYear() > 9999 ? { dateInvalid: true } : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que debes validar que el formato sea correcto antes de evaluarlo con la función date. Una forma seria usando una expresion regular y asegurarte que el formato sea correcto y invocar el error previamente a evaluarlo. Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```js
export const validarFecha = (ctrl: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const dateRegex = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
  if (!ctrl.value || !dateRegex.test(ctrl.value)) {
    return { dateInvalid: true };
  }
  
  const myDate = new Date(ctrl.value.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
  return isNaN(myDate.getTime()) || myDate.getFullYear() > 9999 ? { dateInvalid: true } : null;
}
```

Comment: No funciona sigue saltando la validacion de que la fecha no es correcta, aunque exactamente hay que añadir el regex y validar

Comment: Podrías mostrar un fragmento del código de tu formulario donde defines con los respectivos tags tu <form...  , <mat-datepicker... <mat-error... etc? tambien seria bueno ver el FormControl y la version de angular que utilizar.